# Accessing Field Metadata in a ModelForm with Custom Widget

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I have a Model, ModelForm, and Custom Widget.  My goal was to access the fields verbose_name and help_text in the custom widget.  I couldn't figure out how to get that data in the Widget so I had to pass it to my new SmartTextInput widget in the Model Form?

This just seems hacky, is there a better way?

Here is the ModelForm

```
class LeadForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Lead

    widgets = {
      'first_name': SmartTextInput(label=model._meta.get_field('first_name').verbose_name),
      'middle_name': SmartTextInput(label=model._meta.get_field('middle_name').verbose_name),
      'last_name': SmartTextInput(label=model._meta.get_field('last_name').verbose_name),
    }
```

Here is the custom widget

```
class SmartTextInput(TextInput):

  def __init__(self, attrs=None, label=None):
    super(TextInput, self).__init__(attrs)

    self.label = label

  def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, label=None):
    input_html = super(TextFieldWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)

    html = """<label class="label">""" + self.label + """</label>"""
    html = html + input_html

    return mark_safe(html);
```

Comment: Widgets handle field rendering (value, type etc) labels, help text etc are handled in forms and form fields.
Additionally super should have the className not the inherited class name `super(SmartTextInput,self).__init__(attrs)`